# How to use CKEDITOR.replace after CKEDITOR.inline

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEDITOR in inline mode with multiple editors per page. To create them, I use `<textarea>` tags in the HTML and then run a script that executes `CKEDITOR.inline()` against each of them as soon as the webpage is loaded.

That works fine as long as I define my final configuration in "config.js", but I need to update one of the configuration options dynamically.

Here's my script, using JQuery to loop thru the `<textarea>` elements after the page is loaded. As a diagnostic, I have the `CKEDITOR.replace()` sandwiched between `alert` statements. This code replaces the first `<textarea>` with an editor and displays the first `alert` statement. However, it quits during the `CKEDITOR.replace()` statement and never displays the second `alert`.

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").each(function () {
        editor = CKEDITOR.inline($(this)[0]);
        alert("Before replace, editor=" + editor);
        CKEDITOR.replace(editor, {
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "/new/url/to/be/executed"
        });
        alert("After replace");
    })
});
```

Not only does the second `alert` not execute, but the configuration option I'm trying to update remains as it appears in "config.js".

I think I need to specify something other than "editor" as the first parameter for the `CKEDITOR.replace()` statement, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more research, I discovered that I can set configuration options within the `CKEDITOR.inline` method call. Here's a working version of the script:

```
$(function () {
    $("textarea").each(function () {
        CKEDITOR.inline($(this)[0], {
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "/new/url/to/be/executed"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You do not need to assign the result of CKEDITOR.inline to the `editor` variable, unless you really want to use it later.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor Walc. I tried using the variable in an earlier experiment. I've updated the code here per your suggestion.

Comment: Saved my life. Already spent lot of time researching how to do that. Thanks!